# Power series converges to $\{0\}$ or $ \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Given this theorem:

> If a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges at some point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, then it converges absolutely for any $x$ satisfying $|x| < \left|x_0\right|$.

My text say this theorem has the implication that the set of points for which a given power series converges must necessarily be $\{0\}, \mathbb{R}$ or a bounded interval centered at $x=0$

Could someone explain what the precise meaning of this implication is?

For the set $\{0\}$ does this refer to the case when $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2+... =0$?

And for the set $\mathbb{R}$ is it saying that it just converges to some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or more along the lines of $(-\infty, +\infty)$ i.e diverges?

And what is the point of the third option, i.e the bounded interval centered at $x=0$.Isn't this essentially saying it converges to some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\{0\}$, and thus essentially $\{0\}$?

Comment: What is $x_1$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant when the sum of the terms in a power series $= 0$

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer is exactly what you were looking for; if not, tell me !

Comment: It doesn't mean "converges to $0$" it means "converges when $x=0$...".

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so this is the only case when the $a_n$'s $\geq1$ ? Is there an example for when this case applies?

Comment: What case? Please be clear. My point is, you use the langauge of "converges *to* $\{0\}$" when it is "converges *on* $\{0\}$," which means the values of $x$ when the series converges. You can define $a_n=n^n$ and then get a series that does not converge for any value $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it only converges on $\{0\}$ (radius of convergence $R=0$), it means that it only converges for $x=0$. That **does not** imply that the $a_i$ are null !

If it converges on $\Bbb{R}$ ($R=\infty$, it means that for **any** $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $\sum_ia_ix^i$ will converge.

If it converges on an open centered set or radius $r$($R=r$), it means that for **any** $x$ **such that** $|x|<r$, $\sum_ia_ix^i$ will converge.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the statement now.
What it is saying is actually that the radius of convergence is $x=0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or some bounded interval $b$ such that $|x| < |b|$? Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Iroberto A radius is a number, not a set. That the set on which it converges it $\{0\},\Bbb{R}$ or some centered bounded interval is equivalent to saying that the radius is or $0$, or $\infty$, or a positive real number.

Comment: ^Yup, shortly realised this after my comment and made a sneaky edit haha :P.

Thank you!

Comment: @Iroberto If your question is answered, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the "accept" button on the left :-)